# Python - Does .pop() always execute, even within conditional statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, stack

If i use .pop() within a conditional statement, does the pop still execute even if the condition is not met?

e.g.

```py
if something != stack.pop():
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Say the condition is not met and does not return False, then is the last element of [stack] is still popped?

Edit:

Thanks all for clarifying this. I had assumed that in an IF conditional clause it would check if the pop would meet the condition, but not actually make the change to the list.

Comment: `return  something == stack.pop()` would do the same just in one line.

Comment: @AdrianW this is not relevant as the code itself is just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the item is popped during the evaluation of the condition. Regardless of the outcome, the item has been popped. You can test this by printing the stack in each case.

```
def myfunc(stack):
    if 4 != stack.pop(): # Swap 4 to test
        print(stack) # [1, 2, 3]
        return False
    else:
        print(stack) # [1, 2, 3]
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print( myfunc([1, 2, 3, 4]) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will pop because you called it. No matter where you call it whether a condition or passing it as an argument it will do its job "pop".

If you want safely to check the value and pop at the same time then adding an additional line will not harm.

```py
if something != stack[-1]:
    stack.pop()
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Note: I made this example considering `stack` is a list and as `pop()` will remove the last item from the list so I did `stack[-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

In your conditional, you're comparing to the result of the pop. So the pop needs to be performed, in order to actually compare something.

Think of like this

```
temp = stack.pop()
if 4 != temp:
```

if you want to check if there is a specific item in the stack, and only pop() if that's the case, you can use:

```
# Check if there is anything in the stack, to avoid accessing an invalid position
if (stack.count() > 0 ):
    value = stack[-1]
    if (value == 4:
        stack.pop()
        print( stack )
        return False
    else:
        print( stack )
        return True
```

If you need this more often (or to make the code more readable) you can put it into a small function:

```
def peek( list ):
    if ( list.count() > 0 ):
        return list[-1]
    else:
        return None

if ( peek( stack ) == 4 ):
     stack.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the pop() method would be executed whether the condition is satisfied or not. As any conditional statement like `if(something!=stack.pop())` is executed from right to left. So the pop statement will be executed first and then any comparison will be done.

Below is an example which I used to verify it.

```py
stack=[1,5,7,8,9]
something=9
if(something!=l1.pop()):
    print(False)
else:
    print(True)
    print(l1)
```